# Conceptual question about partitions in a given rectangular grid

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, young-tableaux

Suppose we have a Young diagram $\lambda$ inside an $r \times n$ rectangular grid, i.e. $\lambda \subset [r] \times [n]$. If I were to add just one more box to $\lambda$, obtaining a new partition (Young diagram) $\lambda'$, would $\lambda'$ still lie inside the $r \times n$ rectangular grid? I'm asking this question because I'm trying to show that the complement of Schubert cells $\Omega_\lambda ^o$ inside a Schubert variety $\Omega_\lambda$ is the union (not necessarily disjoint) of all Schubert varieties $\Omega_{\lambda'}$, where $\lambda'$ is obtained from $\lambda$ by adding one box. I think symbolically, what I'm trying to show is that $\Omega_{\lambda}- \Omega_{\lambda}^o= \bigcup_{\lambda' \supset \lambda} \Omega_{\lambda'}$. Anyhow, I will try to prove it myself, but would like some clarification as to whether my intuition is correct.

Comment: This obviously depends on $\lambda$ and, sometimes, on the extra cell.

Comment: What if $\lambda$ is the entire $r \times n$ grid? Then you cannot add an additional box...

Comment: I'm relatively new to Young tableaux, especially from a combinatorial standpoint. But I think I can prove the statement I'm trying to show by usage of simple definitions of Schubert cells and Schubert varieties, and analysis of jump sequences related to a reference flag.

Comment: Your statement is correct once you make it "by adding one box, while staying inside the $r\times n$ rectangle".